# CSS rules with multiple possible values (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The question is simple; using jQuery's `css` function, the computed style of a CSS attribute may be returned, but what if there are more than one style for that attribute being rendered? For example :

```
<div id="foo" style="text-decoration:underline;">Some underline text</div>
```

The instruction `$('#foo').css('text-decoration');` will return `underline`. Now if I change it to

```
<div id="foo" style="text-decoration:underline;">Some underline <span id="bar" style="text-decoration:line-through;">text</span></div>
```

The instruction `$('#bar').css('text-decoration');` will return `line-through`, alright.

But the actual text is *also* `underline`! How can I return both? Do I need to search all ancestors if I want to know if some text is both `underline` and `line-through`? Sounds a bit painful, no?

** **Edit** **

Another problem arises whith this HTML

```
<span style="text-decoration:underline;">some <span id="e1" style="font-weight:bold;">text</span></span>
```

where `$('#e1').css('text-decoration');` returns `none` for some reason, while the text is clearly rendered with an underline.

** **Disclaimer** **

This question is not to debate how the UA renders an element, but if an element hierarchy applies a CSS or not. If one wants to understand `text-decoration` better, I suggest one would [read about it](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html). The question tries to focus on a more generalize matter. For example, it can also apply to this HTML

```
<div style="display:none;">Some <span id="keyword" style="text-decoration:underline;">hidden</span> text</div>
```

where one could want to know if the element `keyword` is visible or not. With the code below, this is simply done with

```
cssLookup($('#keyword'), 'display', 'none');   // -> true
```

** **UPDATE** **

After all the answers and comments, here is, based on [Brock Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688461/css-text-decoration-with-multiple-values-jquery/6688856#6688856) solution :

```
/**
 * Lookup the given node and node's parents for the given style value. Returns boolean
 *
 * @param e     element (jQuery object)
 * @param style the style name
 * @param value the value to look for
 * @return boolean
 */  
function cssLookup(e, style, value) {
    var result = (e.css(style) == value);
    if (!result) {
        e.parents().each(function() {
            if ($(this).css(style) == value) {
                result = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Thank you, everyone, for your inputs.

Comment: I had some fun with this, but not confident that it meets your needs so maybe someone can improve upon it: http://jsfiddle.net/melee/fSESn/1

Comment: yes, the end result is achieved, but I'd like a more "generic solution", what if there are n elements between the two `text-decoration` now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any browser, or the W3C, provides a good way to do this.

A complicating factor is knowing which styles cancel preceding styles (underline versus no-underline, for example).

So, we would need multiple look-up tables or human judgement to know which style actually applied.

Finally, all these methods (3 answers so far) cannot distinguish between a blank, or missing, style setting and an explicitly set `none`.  Obviously the browser can render an explicitly set `none` differently than a blank or missing setting.

For human use, this code should do the trick:

```
function cssTree (jNode, styleName, bShowBlanks) {
    var styleArray  = [jNode.css (styleName)];

    jNode.parents ().map ( function () {
        var style   = $(this).css (styleName);

        if (bShowBlanks  ||  ! /^(none|\s*)$/i.test (style) )
            styleArray.push (style);
    } );
    return styleArray;
}

alert ( cssTree ( $("#bar"), 'text-decoration') );
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/S2YVF/)

**Results:**

```
bar: line-through,underline
el: none,underline

//-- With bShowBlanks = true.
bar: line-through,underline,none,none
el: none,underline,none,none
```

Comment: I am choosing your answer as it is small and got me thinking about a solution (see my question edits)

Comment: Thank you.  Glad we were able to help.

Comment: Still a problem here. The issue is that the spec says text-decoration doesn't inherit, but it's rendered as if it does. Try setting the inner span's text-decoration to none when the outer div is underline. The browser will still render the underline on the inner span.

Comment: @Jason, no, this is documented behavior : "The 'text-decoration' property on descendant elements cannot have any effect on the decoration of the ancestor." Usually, the UA will cut the element in two, splitting it to *disable* the text decoration. Have a child element trying to override the `text-decoration` is a violation and has no effect.

Comment: @Yanick - Yes, that's correct. What I'm getting at is that if you want to know the way the text of an element is rendered, you need to ignore any ancestor "none"s and collect all of the text-decorations that have been applied up the tree. What browser are you using that disables text decoration if it's re-specified in a child? Firefox just sums them all up.

Comment: To clarify, the author states "obviously the browser can render an explicitly set none differently than a blank or missing setting." This is incorrect. An explicitly set none does not get rendered any differently than a blank setting. It cannot override any previously set decorations.

Comment: @Jason: I did not limit my answer, nor my code to decorations.  It works for any style, including `display: none;`.

Comment: @Brock: the difference is that display:none on a child of a display:block element will affect the child. text-decoration:none on the child of a text-decoration:underline element will not. The context of this question is how text-decoration functions and how one can figure out the perceptual rendering of that element.

Comment: @Jason: Your point is moot, because this answer returns the whole relevant part of the tree. Also, the "context of this question" is not just text-decoration.  You'll notice that the 3 upvoted answers, *and the OP's own answer*, were general-purpose functions -- not restricted to any specific style.

Comment: @Brock: Let's try to keep this constructive. Based on the post title, folks will come here looking for a way to extract the text-decoration that's been applied to an element. Anyone looking to understand how text-decoration behaves can refer to the "moot" point above, or who want a way to copy this style to another element and have it look the same can see my answer below.

Comment: @Json, the behavior you are refering is inconsistent across UA, as I explained to you already. The question title suggests `text-decoration` as I did not come across any other situation where the problem arises, but I guess one could apply this to `display:none` as well (to check if an element is visible, even if the element does **not** explicitly set it to `none`). What you are suggesting is simply undefined, or even unpractical. In any case, if anyone's interested, I asked the question for this purpose : https://github.com/yanickrochon/JQuery-UI-RichTextEditor . Cheers.

Comment: @Jason, I changed the question title to reflect better on what is asked here

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
function getVisualCSS(tag, elem){
    var styles = [];
    var thisStyle = $(elem).css(tag);
    if(thisStyle != 'none') styles.push(thisStyle);
    while($(elem).parent()[0].tagName != 'BODY'){
        styles.push($(elem).parent().css(tag));
        elem = $(elem).parent();
    }
    styles.push($(elem).parent().css(tag));
    return $.unique($.grep(styles, function(n){
        return n != 'none';
    }));  
}
```

What it does is, that it checks all of an elements ancestors for a given CSS tag.

For the sake of an "cleaner" array, all `none` values are removed and only unique values are returned.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nslr/bXx46/2/

Comment: @nrabinowitz: Re: `"Ugh - please ignore previous comment"`... You can delete your previous comments. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is not the easy, elegant answer you're looking for, but I have a working option here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/Uu6p3/1/

It's similar to @Thor's in concept, but uses built-in jQuery functions to find all ancestors, map their `text-decoration` styles into an array, filter for unique values not equal to `"none"`, and return the array of styles:

```
/**
 * Generic function to find all values for
 * CSS settings that allow multiple values.
 *
 * @param {String} selector    JQuery selector
 * @param {String} attr        CSS attribute to look for
 * @param {String[]} ignore    Values to ignore
 */
function findAllCssValues(selector, attr, ignore) {
    var temp = {};
    ignore = ignore || ['none'];
    return $.grep(
        // create the array of all values
        $(selector)
            // select element and all ancestors
            .parents().andSelf()
            // put all css attribute results into an array
            .map(function() {
                return $(this).css(attr)
            })
            // make it a regular Javascript array
            .toArray(),
        // now filter for unique values that aren't "none"
        function(val) {
            if (val in temp || $.inArray(val, ignore) >= 0) {
                return false;
            }
            temp[val] = true;
            return true;
        }
    );
}

findAllCssValues('#bar', 'text-decoration');
```

It works for all of your example snippets, as shown in the fiddle. I made it work for any CSS property, though I'm not sure this issue applies to anything but `text-decoration`.

Answer (score -1):

If you try to set the inner span to `text-decoration:none` you'll notice the underline is still rendered from the parent div. The issue is that text-decoration doesn't inherit, but it's rendered as if it does.

So any text element will render the combination of *all* of its parents' text-decorations, even if it or any of its parents have text-decoration set to none.

If you want to know all of the text-decorations that have been applied to the text, you need to walk the chain right up to the top and record the combination of all decorations you encounter, excluding "none".  Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fSESn/4/

```
function findDecoration( elem ) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var found = new Array();
    var dec = "";

    var current = $elem.css('text-decoration');

    if ( current != 'none' ) {
        found[ current ] = 1;
        dec = current;
    }

    var p = $elem.parent();
    while ( p != null && p.get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'body' ) {
        current = p.css('text-decoration');

        if ( current != 'none' && found[ current ] == null ) {
            found[ current ] = 1;
            dec = current + " " + dec;
        }
        p = p.parent();
    }

    return dec;
}
```

Comment: see my response to your last comment, under the accepted answer